# Which CPAN module should I use to calculate ahead a number of business days

Tags: perl, date, cpan

This is a two-part question:

I want to calculate (say) 5 business days ahead in Perl. Accounting for both weekends and holidays. `Date::Manip` does this, but is very heavyweight. Is there a lighter weight module that would do this well?

If `Date::Manip` is indeed the right choice, can you tell me why this doesn't print anything.  The documentation for `Date::Manip` on how to actually output stuff is very thin.

```
use Date::Manip;

my $date = new Date::Manip::Date;

my $err = $date->parse("today");
if ($err) {
     print "Problems: $err\n";
}
$date->printf("It is now %b %e, %Y.\n");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `printf` method should have been named `sprintf`.  It returns the formatted string; it doesn't print it.  Try:

```
print $date->printf("It is now %b %e, %Y.\n");
```

[Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date%3a%3aManip) is probably the easiest way to handle business days, as it has the concept built in.  You could also do it with [DateTime::Set](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aSet) operations (see [DateTime::Event::Holiday::US](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aEvent%3a%3aHoliday%3a%3aUS) for a set pre-filled with U.S. holidays).

There's also [DateTime::BusinessHours](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aBusinessHours), but I've never tried it.

Answer (score 1):

[`DateTime`](http://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) is lightweight compared to [`Date::Manip`](http://metacpan.org/module/Date%3a%3aManip). Also have a look at [`Date::Business`](http://metacpan.org/module/Date%3a%3aBusiness). It can deal with holidays and business days (`addb`).